# Disable EchoSign function in Adobe PDF

Tags: adobe, echosign

I Have a requirement to disable all the options from PDF other than printing and Viewing since it will be sent to some clients and we do not want them to edit it by any means. I have disabled all the signing options , but there is an option called "get others to sign" Powered by echosign .

Is there a way to disable it programatically ?  I am using aspose.

Answer (score 0):

I posted in the aspose forum and they said there was no way to do it programatically.